# favourites with ZF 1.12

Tags: zend-framework

I make new site with News on Zend framework 1.12, I need to add only something from it to my home page, and I have a form for admin to add news, how can I realise it and make possible to mark what news from all must show on my home page ?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far? Your question is very difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Make a new action in your news controller to return only the 5 most recent news.

Option 2: Make a column in your database table for news with the title 'display_on_home_page' and make an action that will return the news that have flag 'display_on_home_page' == true. In your form for submitting news add a checkbox that will set the 'display_on_home_page' flag to true of false.

Hope this helps :)